# How to deploy a rails app with Puma and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I've been following this [tutorial](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/) to deploy a rails 4 app and am getting stuck as it doesn't work.

Point one: I'm not using a domain just yet, only an IP number
Point tow: I've used the default.conf nginx file instead which look like this:

```
upstream turing {
  server unix:///var/run/turing.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost; # change to match your URL
  root /var/www/turing/public; # I assume your app is located at that location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://turing; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

When I visit the ip address, I'm redirected to https://ip address and get a page not available.

If I start the app normally `rails s` and visit ipnumber:3000 the app works as expected.

Can someone tell what am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: 1) Comment `server_name` directive. 2) Check that Puma open `.sock` file.

Comment: How can I check if Puma opens the `.sock` file?

Comment: Check that file is exists and check that you configured it correctly in Puma `config.rb` file (check `bind` directives).

Comment: Where can I find the `config.rb` file? I don't have it in my app...

Comment: [Configuration file](https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration-file) or configure binding use command line arguments as described [here](https://github.com/puma/puma#binding-tcp--sockets).

Comment: The command I'm using to start the app is `bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/turing.sock`. Am I correct in assuming that is how is binding? I haven't created a `config/puma.rb` file. Should I create one?

Comment: Yes, this is correct way of binding and config file is not required.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: do you have set pid and state files to puma?

Comment: do you still need help with this?